# How to check if a Process is Running or Not

Tags: qt

I am starting a process using the below code

```
 QProcess* process = new QProcess();
 process->start(Path);
```

The start method will start a third party application.

If the process is already  running, I  should not call process->start(Path) again.

The process  pointer is private member of the class.

Comment: have you looked at the docs? There are at least 3 different ways to know if the QProcess is running.

Comment: @jdi - I tried QProcess functions, but it always teating as Not Running.

Comment: Be careful with the syntax above. Either make sure it's destructing by manually calling it, or do `QProcess* process = new QProcess(this);` instead if your class inherits from `QObject`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**From the [docs for QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html) ...**

There are at least 3 ways to check if a QProcess instance is running.

[QProcess.pid()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#pid) : If its running, the pid will be > 0

[QProcess.state()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#state) : Check it again the [ProcessState](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#ProcessState-enum) enum to see if its QProcess::NotRunning

[QProcess.atEnd()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#atEnd) : Its not running if this is true

If any of these are not working as you would expect, then you will need to post a specific case of that example.

Comment: Thanks jdi, I think I implemented wrongly, using the process pointer directly i checked the NotRunning enum. I will try again properly.

Comment: @TimeRunCit: I'm not a C++ guy but just curious... If process is a private member, and you do `QProcess* process = new QProcess();`, is that not shadowing it with a local scope version each time?

Comment: You are correct, @jdi  -- this has been vexing when dealing with multiple processes. When checking a list a pointers to a new process against any of those checks, you'll get false-positives.

Answer (score 3):

To complement the [@jdi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496445/jdi)'s answer with a real-life code example:

```
QString executable = "C:/Program Files/tool.exe";
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
process->start(executable, QStringList());

// some code

if ( process->state() == QProcess::NotRunning ) {
    // do something
};
```

`QProcess::ProcessState` constants are:

```
Constant              Value Description
QProcess::NotRunning    0   The process is not running.
QProcess::Starting      1   The process is starting, but the program has not yet been invoked.
QProcess::Running       2   The process is running and is ready for reading and writing.
```

Documentation is [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#ProcessState-enum).